# Uncomplete ajax doesn't allow me to navigate to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a ajax request to a php with an infinite loop. Its an infinite loop because it waits for an event. The thing is that after i click on another page its not working, the browser is loading until the ajax requests finishes. I need if you change the page close the page and move on.

Comment: Can you post your javascript please

Comment: is your ajax call working asynchronously? verify it

Comment: no, its synchronously. the javascript code is simple. i use jquery. $.post(...)

Comment: If it's synchronous, no wonder it doesn't allow you to do anything else, as that's what synchronous requests are. It's likely that it even locks up your browser tab, older browsers might lock up the whole window until the browser decides it has timed out. Change it to an asynchronous request and use a proper callback function.

Comment: damn, sorry ... its asynchronously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Infinite loop is a bad way to achieve event-driven architecture. What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I want to build a chat tool and dont use an ajax request every second just use one ajax request that will wait for an event.

Comment: Take a look here. http://chat.nodejs.org/ .. i want to achive same effect. If you take a look, there is a ajax request pending which ends only when an event occurs